# Do adverbs of quantity modify adjectives?

Tags: adverbes

This page
https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/adverbs/
says that adverbs "may modify verbs, adjective, prepositions, or other adverbs".

It lists some the following words under the category of "Adverbs of Quantity": *beaucoup* (a lot), *très* (very), *trop* (too much).

It's true that I am able to think of sentences where these words clearly modify a verb, or adjective or another adverb:

- I eat a lot. ("a lot" is modifying a verb)
- I run very fast ("very" is modifying the adverb "fast")
- I eat too much. ("too much" is modifying a verb).

But if I click the "Adverbs of Quantity" link, I see other Adverbs of Quantity words that really look like they modify a noun. An example is "un verre de".

- J'ai bu un verre de vin.

In this case, isn't "un verre de" modifying the noun "vin"? If so, is it indeed true that adverbs can modify nouns? (and if so, what makes "une verre de" an adverb, instead of an adjective?")

Comment: *Un verre* = nom ; un verre de vin, une quantité nommée *verre*, représentant un volume normalisé. Pas d'adverbe en vue !

Comment: You're absolutely right; *beaucoup de* etc. are not adverbs. I took a grammatical shortcut but that was clearly a mistake. I've moved those expressions to a separate page - thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: de rien! for me, one of the most helpful (and thus motivating) aspects of learning French is learning to analyse sentences grammatically! (it seems to be helping me identify huge "chunks" of sentences, eg "i don't actually understand that chunk of the sentence but it's some kind of adverbial clause modifying this-here main chunk that i DO understand). so, i've enjoyed looking through your grammar sections, so thanks a lot :)

Comment: Fast is an [adjective](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fast?s=t) not an adverb. [Quickly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quickly?s=t) is the preferred adverb.

Comment: @BenKnoble Fast is certainly an adverb, as well as an adjective. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast#Adverb

Comment: I think (no source) that is a result of conflation with modern day speakers. Originally, (again no source) that fast had no adverbial components other than such figures of speech like fast asleep or hold fast. In other words, i do not think it is intended to mean quickly, but can now due to the way we speak english

Answer (score 2):

French adverbs indeed "may modify verbs, adjective, prepositions, or other adverbs".

- Paul a *beaucoup* **mangé**.
- Paul est *très* **content**.
- Paul est *exactement* **devant** chez toi.
- Paul est *très* **très** énervé.

A lot of the “adverbs” cited on your referenced page are not actual adverbs: Pro-PP (e.g. *ici, là, maintenant, hier, dehors*), Pro-clitics (*en, y*), Pro-QU (e.g. *combien, comment, où, pourquoi, quand*). And others are adverbs which can take NP/noun compléments with the *de* preposition (e.g. *beaucoup, assez, peu*). Finally while *moins* and *plus* are adverbs, *le moins* et *le plus* are not words and hence are not adverbs. Lexical grammatical categories being appropriate only for words.